# Organize imports in eclipse java

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, import, javaimports

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aSpd.jpg)

I'm working on a JUnit project on eclipse , please help me to organize imports ,because im using checkList plugin. I tried source +organize imports also , I tried Control+Shift +o , but both of them did not work . can you help .

Comment: What does 'did not work' mean? What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: ctrl-shift-o sorts them in groups - and works for me on Eclipse. What way do you want to organise them?

Answer (score 2):

[image]To enable this, go to Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Save Actions and then enable Perform the selected action on save -> Organize imports. After this, whenever you save a java file, eclipse will remove the unused imports automatically. 
Little googling might help

Comment: It did not work ! there is nothing like organize imports when I go to selected action on save

Comment: what exlipse version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue:

Go to Preferences -> General -> Keys Click on Filters... and de-select Filter uncategorized commands then Ok.

Then look for the command Go To Symbol in File and select it. Then click on Unbind and then Apply and Close

**Ctrl+Shift+O**. should now work.

Note:

Also unbind any other conflicting commands and leave only one command for **Ctrl+Shift+O** and set the When to Editing Java Source.

Comment: did not work , couldn't understand what you mean by ( then look for the command Go to symbol ?????)